# Where does The Undertaker hide?

Tags: wwe

Recently in the WWE, usually when someone is in the middle of giving a speech in the ring, the lights will go out and when they come back on, [The Undertaker](http://blogstorage.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/SportsBlogcom/48064/0744747001412514806_filepicker.jpg) is standing in the ring.

So where does he come from?

Does he just run out from the back or is he hiding under the ring or in the audience?

Do we know?

Comment: I thought he would just be waiting in the audience and when the lights go out, he quickly jumps from the crowd and goes into the arena.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He comes from under the ring, and the lights are out in real life for longer than they are on television.

As you can see [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5c60GgYIWw), while on television the blackout is 7 seconds, in camera footage taken in the arena, they are actually out for 17 seconds.

Additionally, there is a trap door underneath the ring that the participants can come up through, as evidenced by points 3 and 4 in [this Q&A site question](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Pro-Wrestling-1847/2009/6/wrestling-works.htm).

The relevant points are also cited here:

> 3. The Undertaker is waiting under the ring. There is a TV under there, so he knows when it happens (though the bell sound also tells him). He then comes out to the commentators side (most people look at the ring or the entrance area, so he generally goes unnoticed by flashing cameras) and slowly slides under the ring ropes and stands in the ring. He has to slide under the ring ropes slowly so as the ring ropes don't move, which would give away where he came from.
>
> If you ever see it live, you would see that the lights are off longer than you see on-screen. They edit out so of the time so that it appears that he got there quicker.
>
> 4. There is a trap door under the ring. That is where both The Undertaker and Hornswoggle come from. They come up a bit before they are needed and wait, looking at the TV so that they can get out quicker. For Hornswoggle in particular, it is important that it gets out on cue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Trap Door. Most WWE events happen in regular stadium or arena floors, which **tend not to have secret underground tunnels**. The trap door mentioned would be in the actual ring, so they didn't have to go through the ropes. Of course, injuries due to the trap door (British Bulldog for one) have caused the industry to move away from them.

There are two ways it happens. The first is simple disguises during intermissions. Lights are cut, a video is played so all the attention is on the big screens, and the stage crew comes out. The wrestler in question is among the crew, hiding or disguised. He slips under the ring and changes, waiting for his cue. Of course, there's no proof as this as Wrestling in general sticks to the **"It's real, trust me" and "Even if it's fake, I'm not telling" magician's creed.**

The second is much more entertaining.

Then there's Kane just standing in the crowd ring side before he jumped in at Royal Rumble.

[Boogeyman too.](https://instagram.com/p/yn6T2rR7qC/)

The Undertaker (and his brother Kane) have also popped up through the mat for effect too: